# Why this below code is throwing an error "Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)"?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Question :- Write a program to Validate an IPv4 Address. According to Wikipedia, IPv4 addresses are canonically represented in dot-decimal notation, which consists of four decimal numbers, each ranging from 0 to 255, separated by dots, e.g., 172.16.254.1 . The generalized form of an IPv4 address is (0-255).(0-255).(0-255).(0-255). Here we are considering numbers only from 0 to 255 and any additional leading zeroes will be considered invalid.
Your task is  to complete the function isValid which returns 1 if the ip address is valid else returns 0. The function takes a string s as its only argument .

Code:

```cpp
   class Solution {
    public:
        int isValid(string s) {
            // code here
            if(s.size() == 0 || s.size() > 15){
                return 0 ;
            }
            string temp = "";
            int dot = 3 ;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++){
                if(temp.size() > 3){
                    return 0 ;
                }
                if(s[i] == '.'){
                    if(temp.size() == 0){
                        return 0 ;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(temp.size() != to_string(stoi(temp)).size() || stoi(temp) > 255){
                            return 0 ;
                        }
                    }
                    temp.clear() ;
                    dot--;
                }
                else {
                    if((s[i]-'0')>= 0 && (s[i]-'0')<=9){
                     temp.push_back(s[i]) ;   
                    }
                    else{
                        return 0 ;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(temp.size() != to_string(stoi(temp)).size() || stoi(temp) > 255 || dot != 0){
                return 0 ;
            }
            return 1 ;
        }
};
```

This code is working fine for all the testcases and all the testcases I give as input myself but on submitting, it gives Runtime Error.

Comment: What is `temp`?

Comment: Try running your app with a debugger attached. That way you'll get a backtrace and the spot where the signal was raised.

Answer (score 0):

Try a testcase like `foo.foo.foo.foo` where the elements are not numbers at all, or `9999999999999999.9999999999999999999999.99999999999999999999.9999999999999999` where they are out of the range of `int`.  Then you'll probably see a similar abort.

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) throws an [exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions) if conversion cannot be performed or if the result is out of range.  The judge is probably using testcases where this happens.  When an exception is thrown and you do not catch it, your program calls `std::terminate()`, which on many systems will call `abort()` and raise the `SIGABRT` signal.

If you want to use `stoi`, you will need to use a [try block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) to handle the exception if it should be thrown, and presumably return 0 in that case.

Comment: 9999999999999999.9999999999999999999999.99999999999999999999.9999999999999999 These type of testcases have been managed ,as it is checking the size of temp in every loop and if it is greater than 3 it returns 0 and for testcases like foo.foo.foo.foo  I have added one more check in else condition . The above code is working fine for these cases also now, but still throwing an error on submitting.